# Google Analytics "ga_dispatchPeriod" not working

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I'm following the [Google Analytics Android API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics) to config my `GoogleAnalytics` object, but the parameter `ga_dispatchPeriod` in xml file is not working at all.

**/res/xml/global_test_tracker.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="ga_appName">TestApp</string>
    <string name="ga_appVersion">1.0.0</string>
    <int name="ga_dispatchPeriod">15</int>
</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<application
    ...
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
        android:resource="@xml/global_test_tracker" />
    ...
</application>
```

And the parameter `ga_appName` and `ga_appVersion` was set correctly.

**There is another way** to set the dispatch period, set by code in `Application` class:

```
GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
analytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(15);
```

In this way, we can set the dispatch period successfully.And we can see following logs output:

```
12-25 00:30:01.417 1644-1663/com.google.samples.quickstart.analytics D/GAv4: Dispatching local hits. Elapsed time since last dispatch (ms): 15016
12-25 00:30:01.421 1644-1663/com.google.samples.quickstart.analytics D/GAv4: POST compressed size, ratio %, url: 205, 88, https://ssl.google-analytics.com/batch
12-25 00:30:01.669 1644-1663/com.google.samples.quickstart.analytics D/GAv4: POST status: 200
```

**Now my question is:** why the parameter `ga_dispatchPeriod` in xml file is not working? It's a bug or something I have missing?
Looking forward to your reply! Thanks!

**My sdk version is**: com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:**8.4.0**

Answer (score 0):

Google's doc is really bad for this one. As far as I understand now, the `ga_dispatchPeriod` is just  used for the non-google play services devices as a fallback. The standard one that do have the google play services, use their own dispatch mechanism/timing.